# Uploading files to firebase from local storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am making a chat app where we can upload our file to firebase as in if we select the photo picker in if we select an image and after clicking on it is selected and send and chat chat photo like whatsapp. The photo picker intent is working fine, but when i select the image it is not being able to send an image, thus not being able to upload

The  code intent for firing the photopicker :

```
       mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: is it working?");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY,true);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Complete action using"),RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
                }
            });
```

And the code for picking up photo to be upload is:

```
else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                   StorageReference photoRef = mStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                   //upload file to firebase storage
                   photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                           Uri downloadUrl =   taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                           FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null,mUsername,downloadUrl.toString());
                           mMessageDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                       }
                   });
```

FriendlyMessage.java

package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-21 11:56:08.401 9124-9401/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
04-21 11:56:08.401 9124-9401/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
04-21 11:56:08.410 9124-9327/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-21 11:56:08.440 9124-9404/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-21 11:56:08.446 9124-9401/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/n/armeabi-v7a
04-21 11:56:08.447 9124-9401/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/n/armeabi
04-21 11:56:08.466 9124-9124/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
04-21 11:56:08.466 9124-9124/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
04-21 11:56:08.519 9124-9404/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ifd751822f5)
                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                                    Build Date: 01/26/16 Tue
                                                                                    Local Branch: AU12_SBA
                                                                                    Remote Branch: 
                                                                                    Local Patches: 
                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch: 
04-21 11:56:08.521 9124-9404/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 11:56:08.887 9124-9124/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-21 11:56:09.110 9124-9404/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat V/RenderScript: 0xb7aa3c00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

Storage Database rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want select multiple images?

Comment: Well what goes wrong? Errors? Exceptions? The logcat?

Comment: @kdblue no i don't want to select multiple images

Comment: @greenapps there's no significant error in runtime, but there' something "  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/n/armeabi-v7a"

Comment: @Vishal then your first code snippet is right !

Comment: @kdblue still why isn't it working? will you elaborate?

Comment: @Vishal have you check your firebase storage rule?

Comment: @kdblue, yes, but what do you think my rules should be for the storage?

Comment: can you post your FriendlyMessageModel class code?

Comment: @kdblue i have added the code you request.

Answer (score 0):

Yea , i found the problem

Make all member of FriendlyMessageModel class to public !

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

    public String text;
    public String name;
    public String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In warn of logcat:1)Application info not found.

Comment: can you show mStorageReference where it is reference ?

Comment: in onCreate :    mStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");// I created the chat_photos in the firebase for the storage

Comment: another time it is in the else if code i added above.

Comment: Do you want to see my entire MainActivity class?

Comment: I added  that above in the question

Comment: @Vishal i think its database rule not storage rule !

Comment: Is there any way rule for storage type of images, if that's the thing then how?

Comment: check this ! have you referring `storage` like  firebaseStorage.getReference().child("chat_photos");

Comment: replace this line may be its will work `intent.setType("image/jpeg");`

Comment: There's also one thing i should mention the  requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER is showing me always false, why is that?